# Deserialize multiple json into object c#

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I'm trying to deserialize a json string from a API call with multiple objects but without much success.

JSON:

```
@{
    "purchaseOrders": [
        {
            "supplierId": "500",
            "currencyCode": "EUR",
            "companyId": "LALA",
            "companyName": "LALA",
            "purchaseOrderLines": [
                {
                    "lineNumber": "10",
                    "itemNumber": "255",
                    "itemDescription": "TestItem2",
                    "unitPrice": 24.64,
                    "quantity": 2,
                    "isServiceBased": false,
                    "taxIndicator1": "LAAA5",
                    "taxIndicator2": "4",
                    "unit": "-",
                    "deliveryLines": [],
                    "supplierItems": [],
                    "isActive": true
                },
                {
                    "lineNumber": "20",
                    "itemNumber": "5555555",
                    "itemDescription": "3test, Ind",
                    "unitPrice": 32.56,
                    "quantity": 2,
                    "isServiceBased": false,
                    "taxIndicator1": "LAAA5",
                    "taxIndicator2": "4",
                    "unit": "-",
                    "deliveryLines": [],
                    "supplierItems": [],
                    "isActive": true
                }
            ],
            "orderIdentifier": "261656",
            "supplierName": "Lopes BVBA",
            "orderType": "T",
            "isActive": true
        },
        {
            "supplierId": "5555",
            "currencyCode": "EUR",
            "companyId": "API",
            "companyName": "LALA2",
            "purchaseOrderLines": [
                {
                    "lineNumber": "1",
                    "itemNumber": "448",
                    "itemDescription": "TestItem",
                    "unitPrice": 1563.23117,
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "isServiceBased": false,
                    "unit": "-",
                    "deliveryLines": [],
                    "supplierItems": [],
                    "isActive": true
                },
                {
                    "lineNumber": "2",
                    "itemNumber": "5551",
                    "itemDescription": "Test",
                    "unitPrice": 524.92539,
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "isServiceBased": false,
                    "unit": "-",
                    "deliveryLines": [],
                    "supplierItems": [],
                    "isActive": true
                }
            ],
            "orderIdentifier": "84615",
            "supplierName": "CLopes.",
            "orderType": "T",
            "isActive": true
        }]
```

I created the following model classes:

```
public class purchaseOrder
{
        public string supplierId { get; set; }
        public string currencyCode { get; set; }
        public string companyId { get; set; }
        public string companyName { get; set; }
        public List<purchaseOrderLines> purchaseOrderLines { get; set; }
        public double orderIdentifier { get; set; }
        public string supplierName { get; set; }
        public string Ordertype { get; set; }
        public bool isActive { get; set; }
}

public class purchaseOrderLines
{
        public int lineNumber { get; set; }
        public string itemnumber { get; set; }
        public string itemDescription { get; set; }
        public double unitPrice { get; set; }
        public int quantity { get; set; }
        public bool isServiceBased { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }  
        public List<deliveryLines> deliveryLines { get; set; }
        public string[] supplierItems { get; set; }
        public bool isActive { get; set; }
}

public class deliveryLines
{
        public int deliveredQuantity { get; set; }
        public DateTime? deliveredDate { get; set; }
        public string   deliveryNote { get; set; }
        public bool isActive { get; set; }
}
```

I tried doing this by deserializing the string into a purchaseOrder

```
(purchaseOrder purchaseOrderobject  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<purchaseOrder >(json);)
```

but with no success. I think maybe I have to make use of a dictionary for this but I'm not completely sure how to do that.

Is there a way to do this by getting the json objects one by one an deserializing them like in the following link?

[Deserialize single object](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm#Index)

Comment: What does "no success" mean? It is also not very clear which Json objects you want to get one by one, or why or how.

Comment: You already have a string (not a stream) so there is no obvious problem with converting it to 1 purchaseOrder and use that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You said "with no success", so it's unclear if there's an error or what. But...

I think the issue is your root object. I ran your JSON through [json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com/) and this is what it came up with:

```
public class PurchaseOrderLine
{
    public string lineNumber { get; set; }
    public string itemNumber { get; set; }
    public string itemDescription { get; set; }
    public double unitPrice { get; set; }
    public int quantity { get; set; }
    public bool isServiceBased { get; set; }
    public string taxIndicator1 { get; set; }
    public string taxIndicator2 { get; set; }
    public string unit { get; set; }
    public List<object> deliveryLines { get; set; }
    public List<object> supplierItems { get; set; }
    public bool isActive { get; set; }
}

public class PurchaseOrder
{
    public string supplierId { get; set; }
    public string currencyCode { get; set; }
    public string companyId { get; set; }
    public string companyName { get; set; }
    public List<PurchaseOrderLine> purchaseOrderLines { get; set; }
    public string orderIdentifier { get; set; }
    public string supplierName { get; set; }
    public string orderType { get; set; }
    public bool isActive { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<PurchaseOrder> purchaseOrders { get; set; }
}
```

Try that with `var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);`

Comment: This worked. Count seems to be 200 instead of 201 as i expected but i can work with that. Thank you! Will approve the answer when it lets me

Answer (score 3):

You JSON is an array of purchase order, so you need to deserialize it into a list

```
var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<purchaseOrder>>(json);)
```