# REST API Deserialize Nested Response in Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, json.net

EDIT: Once I have this information deserialized, how can I access the data I need? The only information I need to grab is the TransitTime and the Cost for each accessorial.

I'm working with an API in which I need data from nested objects, but I'm unsure of how to access this information. I've passed my data to the API and have set up new classes based on how the data comes back from the API.

Here's what the response looks like:

```
{"RatingResponse":
  {"Success":"true",
  "Message":"",
  "QuoteID":"57450",
  "LoadNum":"57450",

  "Rates":{
    "Rate":[
        {"SCAC":"TEST",
        "CarrierName":"TEST",
        "TransitTime":"1",
        "ServiceLevel":"D",
        "TotalCost":"983.69",
        "ThirdPartyCharge":"983.69",
        "Accessorials":{
            "Accessorial":[
                {"Code":"400",
                "Cost":"1,655.55",
                "Description":"Freight"
                },
                
                {"Code":"DSC",
                "Cost":"-985.55",
                "Description":"Discount"
                },
                
                {"Code":"FUE",
                "Cost":"313.69",
                "Description":"Fuel Surcharge"
                }
                ]
            },

        "QuoteNumber":""
        },
        
        {"SCAC":"TEST2",
         "CarrierName":"TEST2",
         "TransitTime":"1",
         "ServiceLevel":"D",
         "TotalCost":"983.69",
         "ThirdPartyCharge":"983.69",
         "Accessorials":{
            "Accessorial":[
                {"Code":"400",
                "Cost":"1,655.55",
                "Description":"Freight"
                },
                
                {"Code":"DSC",
                "Cost":"-985.55",
                "Description":"Discount"
                },
                
                {"Code":"FUE",
                "Cost":"313.69",
                "Description":"Fuel Surcharge"
                }
                ]
            },
        
        "QuoteNumber":""
        }
    ]
    },
"AverageTotalCost":"983.69"
}
```

}

I've converted it to C#:

```
public class Accessorial
{
    public string Code;
    public string Cost;
    public string Description;
}

public class Accessorials
{
    public List<Accessorial> Accessorial;
}

public class Rate
{
    public string SCAC;
    public string CarrierName;
    public string TransitTime;
    public string ServiceLevel;
    public string TotalCost;
    public string ThirdPartyCharge;
    public Accessorials Accessorials;
    public string QuoteNumber;
}

public class Rates
{
    public List<Rate> Rate;
}

public class RatingResponse
{
    public string Success;
    public string Message;
    public string QuoteID;
    public string LoadNum;
    public Rates Rates;
    public string AverageTotalCost;
}

public class Root
{
    public RatingResponse RatingResponse;
}
```

The only values I need are the Rate Transit Time and Service Level as well as the Accessorial Costs. I'm a beginner with APIs and am not sure how to return only that information. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you add the code that retrieves the response? Do you already deserialize the JSON into objects or is your question on how to do this? Which version of .NET do you use?

Comment: Sorry, yes, my question is how do I deserialize the JSON to get only the data I need. .NET version is 4.8.

Comment: *how do I deserialize the JSON to get only the data I need* -- you deserialize your `Root` model above and access the required data via its [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-properties).  Is that all you need to know?  Is your question really, *How do I access properties of contained classes in c#?*

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what terminology explains what I'm trying to do since I'm brand new to APIs and JSON. I already have the code set up to send the data to the API, and the response from the API is shown above. All I'm looking to do is say "the response data shows two Rates both with transit data and accessorial costs. I want to store these values so that I can determine what the best rate is." I'm hoping that adds clarification.

Answer (score 3):

you don't need any classes if you use this code

```
    var rate = (JArray)JObject.Parse(json)["RatingResponse"]["Rates"]["Rate"];
    var result = rate.Select(r => new
    {
        TransitTime = (int)r["TransitTime"],
        ServiceLevel = (string) r["ServiceLevel"],
        AccessorialCost = ((JArray)r["Accessorials"]["Accessorial"]).Select(r => (double)r["Cost"]).ToList()
    });
```

result (in json format)

```
[
  {
    "TransitTime": 1,
    "ServiceLevel": "D",
    "AccessorialCost": [
      1655.55,
      -985.55,
      313.69
    ]
  },
  {
    "TransitTime": 1,
    "ServiceLevel": "D",
    "AccessorialCost": [
      1655.55,
      -985.55,
      313.69
    ]
  }
]
```

or you can create a Data class instead of  an anonymous

```
List<Data> result = rate.Select(r => new Data 
    {
     ....
    }).ToList();

public class Data
{
    public int TransitTime { get; set; }
    public string ServiceLevel { get; set; }
    public List<double> AccessorialCost { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like @Serge's answer but I prefer to have results in a class because "I only need..." never holds for very long, right?  Here is a good discussion of loading the JSON into a [complex object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48585029/deserialize-multiple-json-into-object-c-sharp):
Your JSON erred in JSON2C#.com but essentially your root object needs the other classes.  Something like

```
public class Root
{
    public RatingResponse RatingResponse;
    public Rates Rates;
    public Accessorials Accessorials;
}
```

and then deserialize into your complex object

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json)
```

I'm doing this off the top of my head so forgive any syntax errors.

Comment: This is pretty much what I was looking for. I had created the deserialized object, but how do I manipulate the object to pull back the Rates.TransitTime and the Accessorials.Accessorial.Cost? Sorry, really not familiar with how all of this works.

Comment: If one of our answers was what you needed, click to accept an answer so it will close the ticket.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out how to how to return the values from the deserialized object. Is that something you can help with?

Comment: since you have an object is would be something like Root.Accessorials.TransitTime.